# snmp to get cisco switch topology

Tags: switch, snmp

I am two cisco 2960 switch connected together.
Let's assume they are s1 and s2.
I am required to show the switch topology, means I need to use snmp to get which ifIndex of s1 is conneted to which ifIndex of s2.
I know oids to get mac list and ip address but seems like this can't get me the information I want.
How to do that?

thanks,

Brad

Answer (score 0):

If you have CDP enabled then use one of the oids from there, something like 'cdpCacheEntry' might do the job although it's ages since I used them so that may not be the exact one.

Failing that you can use the arp table to find the IP address & MAC address of the neighbouring switch then that should give you the interface as well.